# Fill triangle space in leftCalloutAccessoryView in MKMapView

Tags: macos, cocoa, mkmapview

I tried to add the `leftCallOutAccessoryView` to the `MKMapView`. I added the accessoryView by using the code

```
   annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftAccessoryView;
```

The `accessoryView` is added to the `annotationView` as expected. But small triangle in the accessoryView is left empty.
[image]

[image]

You can also download my sample code [here](https://github.com/Aravindhanarvi/MapView-AccessoryView/archive/master.zip)

Can you please tell me how to fill the triangle with accessoryView?

Comment: Just letting you know, that I have been experimenting with this too, setting frame origins to negative values, adding a CALayer... But it's still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday, I spoke to an MapKit engineer at WWDC, and he confirmed it was an error in MapKit. I've filed a bugreport, so lets hope it will be fixed for macOS Sierra!